Stuck on 'int too large to convert to float' error: How to solve it even after unsuccessfuly trying decimal module?
I've been trying to solve Lagrange's sum using python (with numbers ranging from 0 to 2^1024) but it gives an overflow error when the input has a number of digits higher than 308 (just below 2^1024).
from random import shuffle
# p = a² + b² + c² + d² holds true for all whole numbers.

x = int(input('Write a whole number for the Lagrange Sum: '))

def lagrange_sum(p):
        num = a = b = c = d = 0           
        if num<p:
            a = int(pow((abs(p - b**2 - c**2 - d**2)), 1/2))
            b = int(pow((abs(p - a**2 - c**2 - d**2)), 1/2))
            c = int(pow((abs(p - a**2 - b**2 - d**2)), 1/2))
            d = int(pow((abs(p - a**2 - b**2 - c**2)), 1/2))
            p = []

            squared_values = [a, b, c, d]
            p.extend(squared_values)

            sum_evaluation = x == a**2 + b**2 + c**2 + d**2
            if sum_evaluation:
                print(p)
            else:
                shuffle(squared_values)
                print(squared_values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lagrange_sum(x)

I tried searching for a solution everywhere and I have spent huge amounts of hours trying to figure it out by myself, but in vain. How can I 'increase' python's capacity to perform operations on huge numbers inside a square root? The error occurs when performing the operations on a, b, c and d. I don't want just to perform operations on a single huge number, since the number is an input from the user, whom s/he can choose whatever number, being larger than or equal to 2^1024 if s/he desires to.
Error in question: "OverflowError: int too large to convert to float"

I don't think this is relevant to your question, but you appear to be using p for two different things in your function, which is very confusing.

Floats in Python can’t store values greater than about 1.8e308, as you noticed. There is no way around that.
But you CAN use an integer-only square root method, such as the built-in math.isqrt function. It’s available in the Python standard library from 3.8.
You can also use the decimal module, which supports arbitrarily large numbers with arbitrary precision. They are presumably slower, but that might not matter. Since you don’t want the decimals this will likely be a worse solution than isqrt but I wanted to include it anyway.
from decimal import Decimal

a = Decimal(2**2000)
print(a.sqrt()) # works fine


It's not clear what else you may have tried, because you didn't show it. There should be no "deep" problems if you stay away from binary floating point. For example,
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal("1e10000").sqrt()
Decimal('1E+5000')

There the input had 10001 decimal digits. By default (on a 64-bit box), decimal gives 28 digits of precision and maximum exponent of 999999. If you need more, see the docs for the getcontext() function.
However, be aware: if you ask for, say, a billion digits of precision, a .sqrt() will compute a billion significant digits. That will require a lot of memory and CPU time.

It makes much more sense to simply use an integer square root, rather than using the Decimal class (which would only make sense if you wanted to carry fractional digits).  Now that math.isqrt has been added, doing integer square root has never been easier.

According to:
from sys import float_info

print("minimum float number:", float_info.min)
print("maximum float number:", float_info.max)

Result:
minimum float number: 2.2250738585072014e-308
maximum float number: 1.7976931348623157e+308

So you can't use float for numbers larger than 1.8e308. You must use a multi-precision library like python decimals or gmp library.
And for square roots: Instead of writing sqrt(a**2 + b**2) if m = max([a, b]), it is better to write m * sqrt((a/m)**2 + (b/m)**2).
For example consider our numeric type could hold numbers <= 100. Then a and b must < 10 to not overflow. But in our new form they can be any number < 100.
